# ¿Qué significa: ValueError: x and y must have same first dimension, but have shapes (1, 12) and (12,)?

Tags: python, matplotlib

Este es el fragmento del código que tiene el error:

```
months = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"]

visits_per_month = [9695, 7909, 10831, 12942, 12495, 16794, 14161, 12762, 12777, 12439, 10309, 
8724]

plt.figure(figsize=(12, 8))
ax1 = plt.subplot(1,2,1)
x_values = [range(len(months))]
plt.plot(x_values, visits_per_month)
ax2 = plt.subplot(1,2,2)
plt.show()
```

pero no sé qué estoy pasando por alto.

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Significado de: ValueError with shapes or dimensions](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/401368/significado-de-valueerror-with-shapes-or-dimensions)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si traduzcamos primero el error:

> ValueError: x e y deben tener la misma primera dimensión, pero tienen dimensiones (1, 12) y (12,)

El problema es que el iterable de tu eje <kbd>x</kbd> (`x_values`) tienen dos dimensiones, una fila y 12 columnas, mientras que el iterable con los valores para el eje <kbd>y</kbd> (`visits_per_month`) tienen una sola dimensión, un array de 12 elementos.

El error está en:

```
x_values = [range(len(months))]
```

éstas generando una lista con un solo item, un objeto `range`:

> ```
> >>> x_values = [range(len(months))]
>
> >>> x_values
> [range(0, 12)]
>
> >>> len(x_values)
> 1
>
> >>> len(x_values[0])
> 12
> ```

En realidad es similar a tener:

```
[[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]]
```

La solución es simplemente pasar a `matplotlib.pytplot.plot` el rango directamente:

```
x_values = range(len(months))
plt.plot(x_values, visits_per_month)
```

o si quieres que empiece en uno, que tiene más lógica:

```
x_values = range(1, len(months) + 1)
plt.plot(x_values, visits_per_month)
```

Ten en cuenta que puedes usar los meses directamente:

```
plt.plot(months, visits_per_month)
```

Si alguna vez necesitas una lista con los items de un rango puedes hacer:

```
x_values = [*range(len(months))]
```

o

```
x_values = list(range(len(months)))
```

Ahora si tienes una única dimensión:

> ```
> >>> x_values
> [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]
> ```